# urlopen inconsistent API return format for no content?

Tags: python, url, urllib

I'm using an api http endpoint service where I retrieve some information from their url:

```
response = urlopen(url, cafile=certifi.where())
print(response.read().decode("utf-8"))
```

However, sometimes their service returns nothing and the code above prints either: '' or '[]'

The inconsistent returns caused me issues in my json parsing.

I am wondering if this is expected behavior on the end of urlopen, or if it's a bug from the http endpoint I am using?

Comment: Make your life easier and use the `requests` module instead of `urllib2`.

Comment: If it sometimes sends an empty response, either there's a problem with the API or your URL is wrong. There's nothing wrong with the 2 lines above.

Comment: @Barmar I mean, my question is it supposed to print '' or '[]' when it returns nothing?

Comment: Your code prints whatever it returns. If it returns an empty response, you'll print a blank line.

Comment: Are you seeing two single-quote characters in the output?

Comment: Assuming the API is supposed to return JSON, `[]` is a valid response -- it's an empty array. It shouldn't return a completely empty response.

Comment: @Barmar yes seeing those quotes

Comment: >>> response.read().decode("utf-8")
''
>>> response.read().decode("utf-8")
'[]'

Comment: The interactive REPL shows the representation, so it adds quotes around strings. I was talking about `print(response.read().decode("utf-8"))` that you show in the question. It shouldn't add quotes.